# sub string function in PHP not working

Tags: php, wordpress, substring, substr

I want to display content in limit in wordpress using PHP substring function. I am using this code

`<?php $content = get_the_content();
 echo substr($content, 50); ?>`

but it is not working. It display full content.

Comment: The first param in the substr is the position from where the sub string should return.

Comment: I'd rather use `the_excerpt()`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code may this help you

```
<?php
$content = get_the_content();
echo substr($content, 0, 50);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
$content = get_the_content();
echo substr($content, 0, 50);
```

Or better check for length:

```
$content = get_the_content();

if (strlen($content) > 50)
    $content = substr($content, 0, 50);

echo $content;
```

In a function:

```
echo mytruncate(get_the_content());


function mytruncate($text, $length=50) {
    if (strlen($text) > $length)
        return substr($text, 0, $length);
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: @kingkero haha :) noIdidNotDoItOnPorpouse,JustHurry

Answer (score 0):

I use this code, now it is working

```
<?php $content = get_the_content(); echo substr($content, 0, 50); ?>
```

'0' was missing.